# combining Like statements, to search using "either/or" on values in a number string

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, and am tasked with adding new nomenclature to Location records, using Toad Data Point to update both DB2 and Oracle. I’m trying to query on a number string, specifically on the 1st two digits and the next to last digit, in the string.  Example Loc ID = 54015021, I need to query on spaces #1 and #2 (i.e. 54) and space #7 (i.e. 2).  There are thousands of records, but I’m only updating Loc IDs that have certain numbers in those spaces.  (Not updating the Loc ID itself, just adding new data to different field on same record.)

I have this basic (and clunky) query.  Is there a way to write this in thrift?

```
update pkseclib.ISLOCN00 set ISRCEX = 'RF6' where
islbcd like '40%' and islbcd like '____%06%' or 
islbcd like '54%' and islbcd like '____%06%' or 
islbcd like '55%' and islbcd like '____%06%' or 
islbcd like '56%' and islbcd like '____%06%' or
islbcd like '57%' and islbcd like '____%06%' or
islbcd like '70%' and islbcd like '____%06%'
```

thanks for your help and insight!

Comment: do those strings always have the same length or do they vary in their number of digits?

Comment: `islbcd like '____%06%' AND ( islbcd like '40%' OR islbcd like '54%' and islbcd ...... )`

Comment: Why can't you simply say like `islbcd like '54%' and islbcd like '%21'`